# How to integrate WPFBrowser Application with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xbap

Hello
in 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a48c408e-8ebf-4a79-a0b3-c64d3f0252ad/

My question is:

my XBAP file is "WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap" in a project   WpfBrowserApplication.

in ASP.NET I have to write as it written:

myFrame.Attributes.Add("src", @"http://localhost/XbapTestApplication/XbapTestApplication2.xbap");

this is for    XbapTestApplication2.xbap file

for main :

myFrame.Attributes.Add("src", @"http://localhost/??/  WpfBrowserApplication 1.xbap");

where it should be ? in ASP.NET folder? or i have make solution contains two project ( the ASP.NET and the WpfBrowserApplication)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the compiled XBAP file into a folder in your ASP.Net application, then use the path to this file (through `ResolveClientUrl`).

Comment: I wrote the following but it still gives me " the page not found "
   myFrame.Attributes.Add("src", @"http://localhost/C:/Users/Alaa/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/UserApp/UserApp/XBAPs/WpfBrowserApplication1.xbap");
Isn't correct?

Comment: No; it's not at all correct.  You want `ResolveClientUrl("~/Subfolder/something.xbap")`.